# WebDriverIO :: error: setValue is not a function"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automation, webdriver-io, setvalue

I found the error: `setValue is not a function` when I was trying to set value for an element.
But I came up with a solution like using the async function

```
 describe("Interaction with web elements", function () {
        it("Enter Value in a field", async function () {
            await browser.url('/');
            const Search = await $('#twotabsearchtextbox')
            await Search.setValue('MacBook');
        })
    });
```

Will there be any other alternative way to fix them?

Comment: In what context were you using `setValue` when causing that error?

Comment: setValue(), getText() any methods are not working as sync function ... I can only use async ===>> do you know any solution

Answer (score 0):

it not working because you have not added async and await

```
describe("interaction with web elements",()=>{
    it("enter value in a field", async() => {
        await browser.url('/');
        const search = await browser.$('#twotabsearchtextbox');
        search.setValue('mac');
        await browser.pause(500);
    })
})
```

this should work